# Why cronjob writing outside public_html by default?

Tags: php, server, cron, centos

I've defined a simple cronjob for a file in my public_html folder name cron.php, this file just inserting current date time into log.txt file every minute.

```
/usr/local/bin/php -f /home/{{user}}/public_html/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

this is working every minute, BUT;

`cron.php` located at `/home/{{user}}/public_html/cron.php`

in `cron.php`, $filename value like this:

```
$filename= "log.txt";
```

if i go directly my browser and type http://www.sitename.com/cron.php
it is writing current date time into log.txt file and working perfectly.

crontab doing same thing every minute but , if this script triggered 
via cron service log.txt file writing into `/home/{{username}}/` folder,

so outside of public_html.

how is possible and how can i fix this problem?

Note: if i change filename value as `$filename = "/home/{{user}}/public_html/log.txt";` then it works again. but i dont want to specify fullpath, i need to create a `log.txt` file in same folder.

Comment: Because of different working directories. Use `__DIR__`.

Comment: Specify the complete path of the file

Answer (score 1):

It happens because your working dir for Cron different than your http server's. Just change your crontab to:

```
cd  /home/{{user}}/public_html ; /usr/local/bin/php -f /home/{{user}}/public_html/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Or IMHO better solution is changing it to:

```
wget -q -O /dev/null http://{{your website}}/~{{your username}}/cron.php
```

Comment: first cd command worked thanks. but is it posibble to change cron working directory dynamicly according to user ?

Comment: Try to use cd ${HOME}/public_html ;